# Google Marker GeoChart, create a list of existing markers

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Similar to how the Pie Chart has a list of all of the properties in the chart that you can hover:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Is this possible to do in any way with a markers GeoChart? Everything is working fine except that I would really like to have a list of all the cities on my map and to be able to hover on the entries of that list and have the right marker "react" to that. I haven't found anything that seems to make that possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, use the following chart option...

```
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'both'
  }
```

this will cause the tooltip to show both when the user hovers and selects the chart.

then on your table / list, when the user hovers a row,
use chart method --> `setSelection`
this will cause the tooltip to appear.

```
chart.setSelection([{row: sender.target.parentNode.rowIndex - 1}]);
```

then clear the selection when the user leaves the table row.

```
chart.setSelection([]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart', 'table'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var containerChart = document.getElementById('chart');
  var containerTable = document.getElementById('table');

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(containerChart);
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(containerTable);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    chart.draw(data, {
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'both'
      }
    });

    $(containerTable).find('tbody > tr > td').on('mouseenter', markerShow);
    $(containerTable).find('tbody > tr > td').on('mouseleave', markerHide);
  });

  table.draw(data);

  function markerShow(sender) {
    chart.setSelection([{row: sender.target.parentNode.rowIndex - 1}]);
  }

  function markerHide(sender) {
    chart.setSelection([]);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.flex-static {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-static">
    <div id="table"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While I haven't fully applied your answer, it pointed me in the right direction on using a table and this looks like it definitely is the right way to go. Thanks!.